# Service Fabric Error: Not authorized to connect

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I am attempting to run a Service Fabric example found here:

[Service Fabric Getting Started Sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/)

I am loading it into Visual Studio 2017 CE.  I have set the Fabric app as the startup project and it appears to build and deploy just fine.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 CE]

The Service Fabric dashboard shows everything up and running.

[image: Fabric Dashboard]

However, when I try to connect using the example WebService project I get the following error:

```
WebService> Unhandled Exception: System.Fabric.FabricConnectionDeniedException: Not authorized to connect ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071C43
WebService>    at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeRuntime.FabricEndGetNodeContext(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
WebService>    at System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.NativeFabricRuntimeFactory.GetNodeContextEndWrapper(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
WebService>    at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
WebService>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
WebService>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
WebService>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
WebService>    at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.RuntimeContext.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
WebService> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
WebService>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
WebService>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
WebService>    at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.ServiceRuntime.<RegisterServiceAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
WebService> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
WebService>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
WebService>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
WebService>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
WebService>    at WebService.Program.Main()
```

I've seen where people get this because they have changed the startup project to something other than GettingStartedApplication, unfortunately that's not my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by: `when I try to connect using the example WebService project`? Are you trying to set the **WebService** as the startup project? Where are you getting this error messages from?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set Service Fabric applications(Orange color projects) as the Startup Projects  and not the .Net projects and  then the error should be gone

Answer (score 0):

As I dug through the WebService web.config I found the port to use to connect to the example application (port 8081).  I was trying to launch an instance of the WebService in debug mode (not fully understanding how the example worked) and that's why I got the error message.  Hopefully this will help someone else.